# Keep screen on (prevent screen lock) in Android TWA app

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity, screen-lock

I am a web developer and have a web app (PWA) bundled into an Android app with Bubblewrap and I would like to prevent screen lock while the app is open.

I believe there is no solution involving JavaScript in the web app itself so I'd need an Android solution.

How can I make this happen?

I have found various answers on here that say I should either add `<android:KeepScreenOn="true"/>` to the Android manifest or add `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` somewhere in the code and I have tried to add these snippets in various places in the code, but without success.

Where should I add the code for it to work?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The AndroidManifest.xml of the project created by Bubblewrap is:

```
<!-- The "package" attribute is rewritten by the Gradle build with the value of applicationId.
     It is still required here, as it is used to derive paths, for instance when referring
     to an Activity by ".MyActivity" instead of the full name. If more Activities are added to the
     application, the package attribute will need to reflect the correct path in order to use
     the abbreviated format. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">





    <application
        android:name="Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"

        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.ManageDataLauncherActivity"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/assetStatements" />


            <meta-data
                android:name="web_manifest_url"
                android:value="@string/webManifestUrl" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="twa_generator"
            android:value="@string/generatorApp" />




            <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.ManageDataLauncherActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.MANAGE_SPACE_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />
            </activity>


        <activity android:name="LauncherActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:label="@string/launcherName"
            android:exported="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/navigationColor" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR_DARK"
                android:resource="@color/navigationColorDark" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColor" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR_DARK"
                android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColorDark" />

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_IMAGE_DRAWABLE"
                android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/backgroundColor"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_FADE_OUT_DURATION"
                android:value="@integer/splashScreenFadeOutDuration"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY"
                android:value="@string/providerAuthority"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FALLBACK_STRATEGY"
                android:value="@string/fallbackType" />




            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DISPLAY_MODE"
                android:value="immersive" />


            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SCREEN_ORIENTATION"
                android:value="@string/orientation"/>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/hostName"/>
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.FocusActivity" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.WebViewFallbackActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/providerAuthority"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name=".DelegationService"
            android:enabled="@bool/enableNotification"
            android:exported="@bool/enableNotification">


                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SMALL_ICON"
                    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification_icon" />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <activity
            android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.playbilling.provider.PaymentActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.chromium.intent.action.PAY" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="org.chromium.default_payment_method_name"
                android:value="https://play.google.com/billing" />
        </activity>

        <!-- This service checks who calls it at runtime. -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.playbilling.provider.PaymentService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.chromium.intent.action.IS_READY_TO_PAY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: it's my question too! any answer? :(

Comment: Thomas, if you got the correct solution, share with me please

Comment: Hi! The best solution I’ve found is to use the [Navigator WakeLock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock) in the PWA with `navigator.wakeLock.request("screen")`. I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, yes it's good. thanks. Did you find any solution for safari browser?